# I have a list of pairs, I want to filter this list based on some second pairs

Tags: python, filter

I have a data like below

```
[('A', '2'), ('3', 'B'), ('3', 'C'), ('3', '1'), ('3', '2'), ('3', '4'), ('B', '5')].

permutations= permutations[np.where(not (permutations[:,'A'] and permutations[:,'B'] and permutations[:,'C']) )]
```

I want to filter this based on the second parameter, so that I do not see a 'A', 'B' or 'C' in the second part of the pairs. I want the below result. I used np.where in several ways, but it does not work. What is the simplest way to do that?

> [('A', '2'), ('3', '1'), ('3', '2'), ('3', '4'), ('B', '5')].

Answer (score 1):

No need for `np.where`, you can use a list comprehension with a conditional at the end:

```
[x for x in permutations if x[1] not in set(['A','B','C'])]
```

This works like the following more explicit loop:

```
#set up a list for output
output = []

#for each element in the input
for x in permutations:
    #if the 1th (ie second) element is not one of A,B or C:
    #we use a set for a quicker lookup than a list
    if x[1] not in set(['A','B','C']):
        # add the item to the output 
        output.append(x)
```

Comment: Can you please also show how to filter some list of specific pairs ?

Comment: You would change `if x[1] not in set(['A','B','C'])` to `if x not in [('3', '1'), ('3', '2')])` to filter out those examples you could add an and to do both: `if x[1] not in set(['A','B','C']) and x not in [('3', '1'), ('3', '2')])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use it:

```py
my_list = [(a, b) for a, b in permutations if b not in {'A', 'B', 'C'}]
```

More simple...

```py
my_list = []

for a, b in permutations:
    if b not in {'A', 'B', 'C'}:
        my_list.append((a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myList = [('A', '2'), ('3', 'B'), ('3', 'C'), ('3', '1'), ('3', '2'), ('3', '4'), ('B', '5')]

def func(value):
    a,b = value
    return True if b.isnumeric() else False
    
    
result = filter(func,myList)
for i in result:
    print(i)
```

I've used built-in filter function of python.

Answer (score -1):

```
array = []  # your list here
result = [tup for tup in array if tup[1] not in ['A', 'B', 'C']] # list comprehension (checking if second element of tuple isn't A or B or C)
```

Comment: You should add some explanation so that others can learn from your answer. That's the idea of stackoverflow.